# How can I populate a UserAuth from values in Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack, authentication

This is my custom user authentication setup in my `global.asax` file, but I am currently providing the users manually in the `Configure` method; Is it possible to take values from a Redis server?

For example if user exists and the password is okay, can fill with these details automatically?

```cs
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(()=> 
    new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[]{ new BasicAuthProvider() }
));

container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
var userRepo = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepo);

string hash, salt;
new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("password", out hash, out salt);

userRepo.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
{
    Id = 1,
    DisplayName = "Haluk",
    Email = "hal",
    UserName = "haluk",
    FirstName = "haluk",
    LastName = "yılmaz",
    PasswordHash = hash,
    Salt = salt
}, "password");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can authenticate against a Redis data source. You can either use the built in `RedisAuthRepository` in place of the `InMemoryAuthRepository`, or if you have an existing Redis data set that you want to use instead of the built-in `IAuthRepository` pattern, I have included a solution for that, whereby you extend the `BasicAuthProvider`. The first method is the most straightforward:

### Use the `RedisAuthRepository`:

1. So you need to establish a connection to Redis.
2. Then register your authentication providers.
3. Register the `RedisAuthRepository`, which the authentication providers will check credentials against, and is compatible with the `RegistrationFeature`

```cs
private IRedisClientsManager redisClientsManager;

public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    // Configure ServiceStack to connect to Redis
    // Replace with your connection details
    redisClientsManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("127.0.0.1:6379");
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => redisClientsManager);
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);

    // Setup the authorisation feature
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(()=> 
        new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[]{ new BasicAuthProvider() }
    ));

    // Use a RedisAuthRepository
    var userRepo = new RedisAuthRepository(redisClientsManager);
    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepo);

    // You can then register users as required using the RegistrationFeature
}
```

---

## Alternatively (if you have an existing user authentication dataset in Redis)

You can do this by creating a custom authentication provider that [extends the existing `BasicAuthProvider`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization).

For this code you should also make sure that your familiar with [the ServiceStack.Redis client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#getting-started-with-the-c-redis-client).

### Extend the `BasicAuthProvider`:

This `MyRedisBasicAuthProvider` extends the existing `BasicAuthProvider`, and instead of performing the credentials lookup from an `IUserAuthRepository` as given in your example code, it makes a Redis connection and matches the username to entry in Redis.

The code is fully commented but if there is anything you wish further explained, let me know.

```cs
public class MyRedisBasicAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    // The key at which we will store the user profile. i.e user:john.smith or user:homer.simpson
    // Replace this key with your format as required
    public const string UserKeyFormat = "user:{0}";

    MyUser CurrentUser;

    // Gets an instance of a redis client
    static IRedisClient GetRedisClient()
    {
        // Get the RedisClientsManager from the Container
        var redisClientManager = HostContext.TryResolve<IRedisClientsManager>();
        if(redisClientManager == null)
            throw new Exception("Redis is not configured");

        // Return a client
        return redisClientManager.GetClient();
    }

    // This method is used to verify the credentials provided
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        // Get a Redis client connection
        using(var redisClient = GetRedisClient())
        {
            // Get a typed Redis Client
            var userClient = redisClient.As<MyUser>();

            // Try to find a matching user in Redis
            CurrentUser = userClient.GetValue(string.Format(UserKeyFormat, userName));

            // Check the user exists & their password is correct (You should use a hashed password here)
            return CurrentUser != null && password == CurrentUser.Password;
        }
    }

    // This method is used to populate the session details from the user profile and other source data as required
    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        // Populate the session with the details of the current user
        session.PopulateWith<IAuthSession, MyUser>(CurrentUser);

        // Save the session
        authService.SaveSession(session);

        return null;
    }

    public static void AddUserToRedis(MyUser user)
    {
        using(var redisClient = GetRedisClient())
        {
            // Get a typed Redis Client
            var userClient = redisClient.As<MyUser>();

            // Add the user to Redis
            userClient.SetEntry(string.Format(UserKeyFormat, user.Username), user);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I have used a class `MyUser` to represent the user profile that I have stored in Redis, you can of course customise this class to match your user profile requirements. So this is the basic user profile class:

```cs
public class MyUser
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } // Replace with a hashed password
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

### Setting up ServiceStack with Redis & your custom Authentication Provider:

You will need to configure ServiceStack to use Redis and tell it to use your custom authentication provider. You do this by adding the following to your `Configure` method in your `AppHost`:

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    // Configure ServiceStack to connect to Redis
    // Replace with your connection details
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("127.0.0.1:6379"));
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);

    // Add your custom credentials provider
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new MyRedisBasicAuthProvider()
        }
    ));

    // Add some test users. (If you have an existing Redis user source, you won't need to add test users.)
    MyRedisBasicAuthProvider.AddUserToRedis(new MyUser {
        Username = "john.smith",
        Password = "test",
        Email = "john.smith@email.com",
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Smith",
    });

    MyRedisBasicAuthProvider.AddUserToRedis(new MyUser {
        Username = "homer.simpson",

        Password = "donuts",
        Email = "homer.simpsons@springfield.com",
        FirstName = "Homer",
        LastName = "Simpson",
    });

    // Your other configuration settings ...
}
```

### Notes:

In the example I haven't used a hash password, to keep the example straightforward, but this is trivial to do. Add another field `public string Salt { get; set; }` to the `MyUser` then instead of storing the plain password on `MyUser` store it as a hash of the password and salt i.e. `hashedPassword = HashAlgorithm(password + salt)`. You already have code for it:

```cs
string hash, salt;
new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("password", out hash, out salt);
```

So this solution will now use a Redis data source to authenticate users when a service is secured using the `[Authenticate]` attribute. As with the standard basic provider, the credentials are authenticated at the standard `/auth/basic` route.

**Using the Credentials provider instead of Basic:**
If you want to use a credentials provider for form posts, instead of Basic authentication you can simple replace the word `Basic` with `Credentials` in the code above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: wow that was brilliant thank sso much for taking your time, homer simpson, how can i send that value by textbox or textfield? is it possible to reach global asax?

Comment: @user3790322 You're welcome. If you create another question I can provide an answer showing how to make the login request, as it's a different question to the one you have asked here.

Comment: yes now i added your great code to my global.asax but redis doesnt response i guess :( still not any new data

Comment: @user3790322 Did adding the `RegistrationFeature` as suggested in the other answer sort this now for you? If you still need help understanding how to make a request to the login form, let me know.

Comment: no no, its updated, you rocks mate :) so is there update or delete methods are aavailable too?