# How can I use ServiceStack RegistrationFeature plugin with Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, authentication

I am adding

```
Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

So now I have got at API page for the Register service, but how can I use it with redis? 
Is there any easy way?

```
public object Post(Register register)
{
    var Id = DBService.RegisterUser(register.UserName, register.FirstName, register.LastName, register.DisplayName, register.Email, register.Password, register.AutoLogin, register.Continue);
```

and Redis page:

```
public string RegisterUser(string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string displayName, string email,
                           string password, bool? autoLogin, string @continue)
{
    using (var redisclient = RedisManager.GetClient())
    {
        var redisUser = redisclient.As<Register>();
        var yeniKayit = new Register()
        {
            AutoLogin = autoLogin,
            Continue = @continue,
            DisplayName = displayName,
            UserName = userName,
            Email = email,
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            Password = password
        };
        redisUser.Store(yeniKayit);
        return yeniKayit.Continue;
    }
}
```

I create kind of this code, it saves to redis but this time auth doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the `RegistrationFeature` and use [the Redis setup I suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799995/1295344) (shown below for completeness) then Registrations will work like normal ServiceStack authentication.

```cs
private IRedisClientsManager redisClientsManager;

public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    // Configure ServiceStack to connect to Redis
    // Replace with your connection details
    redisClientsManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("127.0.0.1:6379");
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => redisClientsManager);
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);

    // Setup the authorisation feature
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(()=> 
        new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[]{ new BasicAuthProvider() }
    ));

    // Use a RedisAuthRepository
    var userRepo = new RedisAuthRepository(redisClientsManager);
    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepo);

    // Enable the RegistrationFeature
    Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
}
```

So if you POST a valid registration request to `/register` then the user will be created in the Redis repository.

```js
{
    "UserName": "john.smith",
    "Password": "test",
    "Email": "john.smith@domain.com",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "DisplayName": "John Smith"
}
```

Comment: @user3790322 That's great if it's working now, don't forget to accept that answer. Let me know if you need further help. Good luck with your project.

Comment: i was feel so lonely in this ocean (servicestack) haha thanks for help :) i wont forget your advice hope see soon

Comment: hey again, is there managment like update or delete? and second question redis stores iauthsession, is it way to disable to store sessions or is it should be must create? thanks

Comment: dear scott its worked well i just wonder is it possible to change ctypted user logins by cs code?

Comment: oh i am sorry dude you are my friend also i asked you to be my social friend on facebook or googe + it must be something wrong i accept your message sorry friend :) please never sad i hate to see sad people

Comment: i just wonder hi again by the way, how i can limit to register? for example someone can regist hisself with rest codes, is there any auth for register?